# Angular 2 - постоянная проверка соединения с интернетом

Tags: javascript, angular2

Задача такая - есть приложение на AngularJS 2 и необходимо создать сервис, который бы постоянно крутился бы в цикле и проверял, доступно ли в данный момент соединение с интернетом. Как можно реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: А зачем вам нужен такой функционал? И вопрос по `angular 2` или `angularjs`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Angular 2. Нужен для того, чтобы если пропадало соединение, сохранять результат некоторых вычислений в localStorage, чтобы избежать утери данных.

Comment: Есть два общих способа. По таймауту посылать запрос на сервер. Использовать веб-сокеты. Веб-сокеты лучше в плане производительности.

Comment: А почему бы просто не сделать так: если не удалось сохранить состояние на сервер (нет соединения) - сохранить в локал сторадж.